# How to split string

Tags: excel, excel-2007, split

I have a string in MS excel that I would like to split.

Cell looks like this, but not every cell is the same.

```
RENAULT KANGOO Rapid (FC0/1_) 1.9 dCi 4x4 (FC0V) or
RENAULT CLIO II Box (SB0/1/2_) 1.9 D (SB0J)
```

From this I would like to get:

```
RENAULT | KANGOO |       | Rapid | 1.9 dCi 4x4 or  
RENAULT | CLIO   | II    | Box   | 1.9 D
```

In five different cells/rows.

Comment: Do you have any attempts yet? Would you perhaps prefer a VBA solution or formulaic approach?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the split criteria? It looks like you are trying to split based on space but don't want any value with brackets. However in row 1, you want a blank space before Rapid ... how?

Comment: Jerry, i would prefer formulaic approach. I am not familiar with vba.

Comment: Pankaj Jaju, i would like to split based on space but without value in brackets but not necesery. I would like to sort into rows Mark, Model, Model series or make, Chassiss, ccm. Some cars have Model make some dont. It is the same with some other data like some have the name for the chassiss others dont.

Comment: That is going to be hard. Because there is only space to play with in terms of split condition. And since entire row's data is in one cell, I don't see if this can be split as per your requirement (especially the model series).

Comment: Ok, what about the brackets. If i would split till the first bracket. And also remove them. So I would get RENAULT KANGOO Rapid | 1.9 dCi 4x4 in two cells. Would that be easyer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of functions FIND and MID (or LEFT or RIGHT instead of MID in the simplified version). You'll probably have to experiment a bit given the not so well defined structure of input data.